# Can't access relationship as property if use join statement in eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi everyone is there any particular reason why when I do something like that

```
$order = Order::with(['company'])->find($id); 
dd($order->company)
```

returns the value of company but if I do something like

```
$order = Order::with(['company']->join('customers', 'orders.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')->find($id);
dd($order->company)
```

it returns null, but if dd($order) shows relationship present and $order->toArray() show that company is there. I simply can't access it like a property if I add join statement to query.

Comment: Why don't you preload both relationships?

Comment: I am trying to minimize the number of queries as currently, I have 18 of them.

Comment: I might be joining company as well this code has been written just to display the concept

Comment: I would do some investigation on whether the join method suits the query builder that `with` returns. But still, I would go with eager loading both relationships as that would execute only three queries.

Comment: I don't need customers whole model, I need only first name and last name for the current purpose and the same happens with the rest of relationships. I am trying to figure out why I can't access relationship as property on the model when join method is used.

Comment: What's the result of `dd($order->getAttributes());`?

Comment: It returns the order but `'company' => null`, without join statement company is absent

Comment: Is there a `company` column in the `customers` table?

Comment: yes and  I think I understand where its going now.

Comment: fix will be select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to limit the selected columns:

```
$order = Order::select('orders.*', 'customers.first_name', 'customers.last_name')
    ->join('customers', 'orders.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->with('company')
    ->find($id):
```

Comment: Well damn me. How could I have missed that. You can only gain this kind of knowledge by experience. If your relationship is same as the column of the joined table make sure you limit your query in order not to mingle them